# Getting Travis CI to run unit tests for a specific PyPI package

Tags: unit-testing, pip, travis-ci

I wrote a C extension that is designed to improve the performance of a Python library.  The extension is installed as an extra using pip:

```
# Install the library by itself:
pip install pyota

# Install the Python library w/ C extension:
pip install pyota[ccurl]
```

The Python library prefers the C extension if present, but it will fall back on a pure-Python implementation:

```
# iota/crypto/__init__.py
try:
  from ccurl import *
except ImportError:
  from .pycurl import *
```

A simple way to test the C extension is to install the extension and then run unit tests for the Python library.  There's ample coverage, such that if the unit tests pass with the C extension installed, I can be confident that the C extension behaves identically to the pure-Python implementation.

However, this is proving to be quite tricky to automate.

I'm trying to get Travis CI to do something like this:

1. `pip install -e .` (i.e., install `pyota[ccurl]` into venv).
2. Install `pyota` source dist into cwd (source dist includes unit tests).
3. `nosetests pyota/tests` (run unit tests from local source dist).

However, I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to accomplish step 2.

*How do I instruct Travis CI to download a source distribution via pip so that it can run the unit tests?*

Answer (score 0):

This feels a bit like a brute-force solution (well, let's be honest here; it feels like I'm trying to solve the wrong problem), but this configuration gets Travis to download the Python library and run the unit tests:

```
# .travis.yml
...
script:
  - pip install nose mock
  - 'pip download --no-deps --no-binary :all: --dest pyota --pre pyota'
  - tar -zxf pyota/PyOTA-*.tar.gz -C pyota --strip-components=1
  - nosetests pyota/test
```

I was unable to figure out how to predict what the archive is named once `pip download` finishes, so I opted to glob for it.